# C# Chart Growth direction

Tags: c#, charts

Q:In the Chart, the Chart growth default direction is from bottom to top.

```
 series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           series.Points.AddXY(i, (rand.Next(3600, 7200)), 
                                  (rand.Next(30000, 80000)));
```

(1) from bottom to top. (↑)

[image]

**How can i change the direction ? From Top to buttom!!** (↓)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try iterating from the end to 0, like this:

```
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
        for (int i = 2; i > -1; i--)
            series.Points.AddXY(i, (rand.Next(3600, 7200)), (rand.Next(30000, 80000)));
```

With the following code I have manager to create two charts with same data but different growth direction:

```
int[] val = new int[3];

chart1.Series.Add(series);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    val[i] = rand.Next(30000, 80000);
    series.Points.AddXY(i, val[i]);
}


Series series2 = new Series();
series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
chart2.Series.Add(series2);
for (int i = 2; i > -1; i--)
{
    series2.Points.AddXY(i, val[-i+2]);
}
```

If the user is granted with the possibility of changing the direction you could recreate/reprint the chart anytime the user changes the direction. I know it is far from being optimal but for know it is the best I could advice.

If the answer doesn't meet your needs here are some samples (in the `download` section) you might find them useful:

[mschart](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

Comment: Thanks your answer!!! 
But i add the points by dynamic.
I want the user see the operation is Top to bottom.

maybe C# chart have a Parameter to change the direction?

Thanks Tafari!

Comment: @user2894287 at the moment I do not have the possibility to check it, as I do not have the proper environemnt, but I have provided an link in my answer with some chart samples, hope it help.

Comment: And well you could recreate/reprint the chart anytime a user changes the direction I know it is far from being optimal, but that's all I could advice for now.

Comment: I appreciate your help :) It make me think about the other way to fix this problem. I will try this . Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to share your results when you are done : )